# Switch to workspace left/right/above/below keyboard shortcuts do not work

Tags: workspaces, shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher

As the title says, I cannot use the keyboard shortcuts to switch to nearby workspaces, as they are correctly set in `keyboard -> shortcuts -> navigation`.

Any idea what could have caused this or what should I check to see if everything is alright?

Comment: In system properties -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> navigation on the bootton there are switch to workspace shortcuts are they set ?

Comment: yes, they are set, this is why this is problematic

Comment: Maybe something in ccsm has overridden this settings. Try to look in plugins such as cube

Comment: cube is deactivated, I am using "expo"

Answer (score 0):

The compiz plugin responsible for viewport switching is `Desktop Wall` . You can check if it is enabled with  this command in terminal :

```
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins | grep --color -i "wall"
```

If you don't have the word `wall` highlighted there, you will need to have it enabled. It can be done via `dconf` however , I recommend installing `CompizConfig Settings Manager` ( with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` ) and making sure `Desktop Wall` plugin is checked:

[image]